How to differentiate the grouping effect and the random effect when fitting GAM model?
according to the definition:

The Hierarchical Generalized Additive Model (HGAM) allows modeling of nonlinear functional relationships between covariates and outcomes where the shape of the function itself varies between different grouping level
On the other hand, Generalized Additive Mixed Model (GAMM) is an extension of generalized additive models incorporating random effects. GAMM are widely used to model correlated and clustered responses.

My question is how to differentiate the grouping effect and the random effect. I have a dataset about the number of contacts at different locations during three periods. 
Because this data is repeated measures, so each participant has at least two results. The head of the dataset is like below. I think I should take the place and the token as the grouping effect, and the Bundesland as the random effect. But how to build a model with two grouping effects?
The model I built before is to first divide the data according to the place, then fit the model separately. But it loses some information by doing this.
      token      Datum period     place n age  birthdate parttype wave    sex    country      Bundesland hh_size  marital
    1  0010 2020-08-01      1 Household 0  64 1957-01-01    adult base   Male In Germany Rheinland-Pfalz       1 Divorced
    2  0010 2020-08-01      1      Work 0  64 1957-01-01    adult base   Male In Germany Rheinland-Pfalz       1 Divorced
    3  0010 2020-08-01      1 Education 0  64 1957-01-01    adult base   Male In Germany Rheinland-Pfalz       1 Divorced
    4  0010 2020-08-01      1    Others 0  64 1957-01-01    adult base   Male In Germany Rheinland-Pfalz       1 Divorced
    5  0020 2020-08-02      1 Household 0  57 1964-01-01    adult base Female In Germany     Brandenburg       1  Widowed
    6  0020 2020-08-02      1      Work 0  57 1964-01-01    adult base Female In Germany     Brandenburg       1  Widowed
                                                                                    education
    1                                Intermediate school leaving certificate (Mittlere Reife)
    2                                Intermediate school leaving certificate (Mittlere Reife)
    3                                Intermediate school leaving certificate (Mittlere Reife)
    4                                Intermediate school leaving certificate (Mittlere Reife)
    5 General or subject-specific university entrance qualification/Abitur (Gymnasium or EOS)
    6 General or subject-specific university entrance qualification/Abitur (Gymnasium or EOS)
                                                                                                                   perfession         employment
    1 Completed training at a technical school, master craftsman's school, technical college, vocational or technical academy Employed full-time
    2 Completed training at a technical school, master craftsman's school, technical college, vocational or technical academy Employed full-time
    3 Completed training at a technical school, master craftsman's school, technical college, vocational or technical academy Employed full-time
    4 Completed training at a technical school, master craftsman's school, technical college, vocational or technical academy Employed full-time
    5                                   University degree (e.g. diploma, master's degree, state examination, master's degree) Employed full-time
    6                                   University degree (e.g. diploma, master's degree, state examination, master's degree) Employed full-time
                transportation            marital_2cat       education_2cat employment_2cat  weekday weekend single       region transportation_2cat
    1 Car, motorcycle, scooter divorced/single/widowed Non-Higher Education        Employed Saturday Weekend    yes West Germany          Not public
    2 Car, motorcycle, scooter divorced/single/widowed Non-Higher Education        Employed Saturday Weekend    yes West Germany          Not public
    3 Car, motorcycle, scooter divorced/single/widowed Non-Higher Education        Employed Saturday Weekend    yes West Germany          Not public
    4 Car, motorcycle, scooter divorced/single/widowed Non-Higher Education        Employed Saturday Weekend    yes West Germany          Not public
    5                  Bicycle divorced/single/widowed     Higher Education        Employed   Sunday Weekend    yes East Germany          Not public
    6                  Bicycle divorced/single/widowed     Higher Education        Employed   Sunday Weekend    yes East Germany          Not public
    > 


bam(n ~ s(age, by = period, k = 12) + 
            s(hh_size, by = period,  k = 9) +
            period * weekend + 
            period * employment_2cat + 
            period * transportation_2cat +
            period * education_2cat +
            period * marital_2cat +
            period * region +
            s(token, bs = "re") + s(Bundesland, bs = "re") ,
          data = halle_data_household,
          method = "fREML", discrete = TRUE,
          family = nb(),
          nthreads = c(4,1))


You can simply add another term for each random intercept.

Thanks, I figured it out finally. I will put my solution there.

Answer to my own question. Token and Bundsland are taken as random effects. The variables of place and period are taken as the interaction terms.
update: after taking comments from @Gavin Simpson and reading several posts, I corrected the formula by adding period * place to the main effect. So below is the updated codes.
The model is fitted as below.
bam(n ~ period * place + 
        s(age, by = interaction(period, place), k = 8) + 
        s(hh_size, by = interaction(period, place), k = 9) + 
        s(token, k = 864, bs = "re") + s(Bundesland, k = 16, bs = "re"),
        data = halle_data,
        method = "fREML", 
        family = nb(), 
        discrete = TRUE)

Using the draw function from package gratia, here is the gratia plotting output for the model.

The first three subplots on the top-left are the distribution between age and the outcome variable at the location Household for three periods. The three subplots on the top-right are the distribution between age and the outcome variable at the location of Education for three periods.

You should note that your model is incorrect: you use interaction(period, place) for the by factor so you get one smooth per combination of period and place, yet you do not include the group means for each combination. You need period * place in the formula.

Also, your figure doesn't correspond to the model you showed.

Thank you, I did not know it. I am correcting it now. Yes, the figure is wrong. I pasted another figure yesterday.

bam(n ~ period + place +
s(age, by = (period * place), k = 8) +
s(hh_size, by = (period * place), k = 9) +
s(token, k = 864, bs = "re") +
s(Bundesland, k = 16, bs = "re"),
data = halle_data,
method = "fREML",
family = nb(),
discrete = TRUE) This is the model I fit, however, an error dropped. Error in [.data.frame(mf, termi) : undefined columns selected

I created an interaction variable: halle_data |>
mutate(periodplace = interaction(period, place, drop = TRUE)) -> halle_data, then use this new variable as the interaction term, the results are the same between the two models. bam(n ~ period +
place +
s(age, by = periodplace, bs = "sz", k = 8) +
s(hh_size, by = periodplace, bs = "sz", k = 9) +
s(token, k = 864, bs = "re") +
s(Bundesland, k = 16, bs = "re"),
data = halle_data,
method = "fREML",
family = nb(),
discrete = TRUE)

I figure it out, thank you Gavin! I will edit my answer.
